# rake db:migrate StandardError macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-sierra, dbmigrate

I'm getting a so called 'StandardError' when I run rake db:migrate. I ran this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And got this 'StandardError' in a Mac Terminal

[image: Screenshot of error in Mac Terminal]

Comment: are you trying to run migrations for a rails app you've cloned from somewhere? or is this a new app you're working on?

Comment: @eiko This is an app I'm working ins

Comment: Why try to include a screen shot of text when the text itself would be easier to post and easier for us to read?

Comment: @muistooshort I was having trouble with making it readable when I posted it directly as code. I don't see it as a big problem though. Hope it's all good. All I want is a comment on how to fix this.

Comment: Yes please, we prefer text. Images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and thus make it harder to satisfy our goal of helping as many people as possible. Use the code formatting tool to present console I/O.

Comment: @halfer I will change this in my future posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through all your migration files in `db/migrate` and change this line:

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

to look like this instead:

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
```

---

I'm assuming you're working with an old / poorly maintained app. If you're generating migrations yourself and they're not automatically including `[5.0]` at the end, then you should probably open a second question to figure that part out.